# Remove start/end double quotes from jquery array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I am getting data from php with this jquery:

```
var reserved=null;
$.ajax({
        url: 'test.php',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            reserved=data;
        } 
     });

var res = new Array(reserved);
console.log(res);
```

Data from php looks like this: `"2014-02-28", "2014-03-01", "2014-03-02"`
*console.log* returns this: `[""2014-02-28", "2014-03-01", "2014-03-02""]` and jquery doesnt work
But when I enter dates manually instead of *reserved* then it works.
Like this: `var res = new Array("2014-02-28", "2014-03-01", "2014-03-02");`
And *console.log* `["2014-02-28", "2014-03-01", "2014-03-02"]`
So problem as I see it is in those quotes at start and end of array. Can they be removed?

Comment: PHP is creating the returned array here, we need to see the PHP code.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/a35mE/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)**

```
var res = JSON.parse('['+reserved+']');
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/a35mE/)

Comment: Thank you. Found it very helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
var res = $.parseJSON(reserved);
console.log(res);
```

EDIT: you don't need to create an array.

Answer (score 0):

you need to encode the result inside your php like this:

test.php file

```
//your code
echo(json_encode($your_array);
```

and your ajax:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'test.php',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            reserved=data;
        } 
     });
```